# GameScene SpriteKit does not fit iPhone X display

Tags: ios, swift, layout, sprite-kit, iphone-x

I have been looking and trying all solutions I've found on the internet. None of them are working as expected. My game requires a border as shown in the image attached. It works fine with iPhone 8 and 8 Plus. On X, I cannot seem to find the proper way to fill it without disrupting my game scene. Even if I use `resizeFill` or `aspectFill` it cuts off the important contents from my gaming area. The one in the image is `aspectFit` but gives me black borders which does not look good and is not taking advantage of the larger screen. The layout in the GameScene file is not according to iPhone X. How can I make the game optimised for all of these 3 devices. I know how to do it for an app on storyboard with constraints and auto layout, but I am kinda new to SpriteKit and GameScenes. I do not mind even if the black borders on the iPhone X is filled the colour of my border. But I do not know how to implement it and I do not think its the best practice for optimising games for all of these 3 devices. Thank you in advance for your help.[image: iPhone X, 8 and 8 Plus]

Comment: This is covered all over the place,  you need to make your scene size the iPhone X size, and allow the 8 to crop.  You will never get the scenes to match on all devices because of different aspect ratios, so you need to make some designer choices

Comment: Is there a way I can change the size of the GameScene of SpriteKit. Right now it's on the 8's ratio. How can I change that?

Comment: You change it in the SKS file

Comment: How and where? Can’t seem to find it. :(

Comment: Seriously?  Did you use the template apple provides? I am not going to hold your hand with trivial things here. Walk through your project and understand everything in it.  Just keep clicking.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I guess you want something like this right

### 1. Resizable scene

First of all you want your scene to resize (changing size and aspect ratio) in order to perfectly match the display. So open `GameViewController.swift` and set

```
scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
```

### 2. Resizable rectangle

Now you want to create a rectangle matching the perimeter of your scene.
That's easy, open your scene and write what follows

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let rectangle = SKShapeNode(rect: self.frame)
        rectangle.strokeColor = .green
        rectangle.lineWidth = 20
        addChild(rectangle)

    }
}
```

### How does it work?

As you can see I am creating a rectangle using the same frame of the scene. So, you are sure your rectangle will always match the perimeter of the scene (which will match the display).

That's it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I will try that once I get home. But will the image on the iPhone X crop or be stretched?

Comment: The rectangle is neither cropped nor stretched. It is just resized. BTW if you need to use a bitmap image you can choose to crop or resize it.